# How to loop through an ejs array on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to make a google form clone app and I am using ejs for rendering and node.js for backend.

This is a part of my code here:

```js
const ques_len = parseInt("<%= subs[0].questions.length %>");

for(var i = 0; i < ques_len; i++) {
  const type = "<%= subs[0].questions[i].optn_type %>";
  // console.log(type);
}
```

This is the schema of the `subs` array:

```js
const submitFormSchema = new Schema({
  form_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  questions: [{
    ques: String,
    quesNum: Number,
    optns: [String],
    ansOptn: [String],
    optn_type: String
  }]
});
```

`subs` is the array of total submissions for that form, `questions` is an array of objects that has all the question details of that form and `optn_type` is the type of the options which that question has like radio, checkboxes, text, date, and time.

So, I have to loop through the questions in one part of my code but I am getting an error - `Cannot read property 'optn_type' of undefined` but when I replace `i` with numbers like 0, 1, 2, ... I get the option type. I think it can't read the variable `i` because it is in a `ejs` variable but I don't know how can I loop through that array any other way

What am I doing wrong here? Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

You said that replacing `i` with 0 to 2 works, but that when you loop through your array it is not working. I see that you're currently not using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) nor string concatenation to generate your string in your loop.

Basically, when you're looping through your current code `"<%= subs[0].questions[i].optn_type %>";`, the `i` is being used as a character - and not as a variable.

You can insert the current value of your `i` into your type string in your loop by using the below code. This is how it is done with template literals.

```
const type = `<%= subs[0].questions[${i}].optn_type %>`;
```